# Extracting value from Json response of POST request in Jmeter using Json Extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

[Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyHc3.png) [Json Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5KaC.png) [Get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SviGX.png) [debug sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVolH.png) [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOLZo.png) I'm using Jmeter for stress testing of my application. Test plan that I'm building has a POST request which creates a user and the next PATCH request updates it. Basically I want to extract user_id from Json response received after POST request and add that id in the body of the next request. For that I use Json extractor in my POST request and when I check Debug Sampler the value is successfully stored. But when I try to use extracted user_id in any subsequent requests of the same thread it is not recognized. However when I tried to extract user_id of already created user with GET request then this user_id is normally recognized by other requests. I'm not sure whether Json extractor is not normally used with POST requests or I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to provide an answer without seeing the screenshot of your Test Plan or even better Schematic View (the option is available under "Tools" main menu entry since [JMeter 5.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-5.1/))

[image]

Given you're able to see the extracted value in the debug sampler I can think of 2 possible options:

1. Your syntax of referring the `user_id` variable is wrong, in [JMeter the Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) are accessed like `${user_id}`
2. Placement of your JSON Extractor is wrong, i.e. instead of putting it as a child of a specific sampler you have it at the same level as all Samplers therefore it's getting applied to the Debug Sampler as well and the extracted value gets overwritten. See [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) user manual section for more information

Comment: I tried to recreate the issue with reqres website and got the same result. What you mentioned above was also considered [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyHc3.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5KaC.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SviGX.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVolH.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOLZo.png

Comment: Man, your [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) clearly states that there is `${userId_1}` variable and you for some reason are trying to use `${userId}`. Either change it to `${userId_1}` or change `-1` to `1` in the "Match No" input of the JSON Extractor.